# Overwriting JavaScript function with dynamically loaded script during runtime

Tags: javascript, ajax

I just wanted to see if this approach is architecturally sound.

I have a main.js that gets loaded on init, and dynamic external scripts that get loaded during runtime (one at a time). There is a function in main.js that gets called each time it needs to handle a message received from the server, I want to be able to have that function call the external scripts custom handle function and to do this I'm specifying a function with the same name in the external script so that it overwrites the function in main.js each time a new script is loaded.

From my trials it seems to work, with some caveats, so I have some questions:

Is there a better way to do something like this?

What could possible go wrong with this approach?

I realize that scripts cannot be cleared from cache without refresh / navigation but my scripts are relative small in size so I don't think this will be a problem.

Edit with more info:

I need this to have a single page structure so navigation is out of the question. I also don't know what the next "page" will be until the server sends a message, so the resources have to be retrieved during runtime with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a call in your main function:

```
var call=false;
function onsomething(){
//general stuff needed in both
if(call!=false){
call();
}else{
//original main code
}}
```

And simply set this in your later loaded js:

```
call=myfunction;
function myfunction(){//new main code}
```

Comment: OK so this is just to make sure the external function is actually loaded before I call it.

Comment: Yeah but with this your original function is not overwritten wich you can use to define variables you use in both functions in the main js and just switch to the part that is really needed to be switched